# Как посмотреть код программы на ассемблере?

Tags: c++

Как посмотреть код программы на ассемблере?

devC++, windows 10 x64

Comment: Посмотрите ключи вашего компилятора. Например у gcc ключ -S генерит ассемблерный код

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [дизассемблером](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80), например, таким как [IDA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA). Если вас интересует, во что именно компилируется ваш собственный код (а иначе зачем бы вы ставили метку C++? :)), то многие компиляторы (если не все :)) генерируют ассемблерный листинг наряду с объектными файлами. В Visual C++ для этого служит ключик /Fa, в GCC, насколько я знаю, ключик -S.

Comment: где нужно написать `-S`?

Comment: @васёк2003 а как Вы запускаете компиляцию?

Comment: @alexolut из `ide` прямо, я нашёл этот параметр, но пишет, что не удалось запустить программу/компонент из-за несовместимости с 64-разрядной версией windows

Comment: @васёк2003 какая ide, ОС и т.д? Опишите всё это путём редактирования Вашего вопроса, а не в виде комментариев. Так будет правильнее.

Comment: @alexolut сделал

Comment: @васёк2003  DevC++ - это **среда**, а не компилятор. Скорее всего, у вас работает MinGW, но в принципе среду можно настроить для работы с массой других компиляторов...

Comment: @Harry мне сказали написать `ide`, а компилятор `GCC 4.9.2`

Comment: @Harry я в `compiler options` нашёл пункт `do not assemble, but output assembler code (-S)`, поставил его, теперь при запуске `exe` файла пишет, что не совместим

Comment: `неподдерживаемое 16-разрядное приложение`

Comment: @васёк2003 Лично я работаю в VC++ 2015, так что боюсь вам что-то подсказывать - по поводу GCC...

Comment: @васёк2003 Ой. Так создавайте, конечно же, 32-разрядное приложение как минимум. 16-разрядные в 64-разрядных версиях Windows не работают...

Comment: @Harry получается, устанавливая флаг `-S`, создается 16-разрядное автоматически, я не знаю, как другое сделать

Comment: @Harry `Visual Studio 2015` у меня тоже есть, как там сделать?

Comment: @васёк2003 В командной строке - /Fa. В среде можно  поставить ключ - Отладка - Свойства [проекта] - С/C++ - Командная строка - дополнительные параметры, ввести там /Fa. Или просто запустить отладку и смотреть в соответствующем окне...

Comment: @васёк2003 я сейчас попробовал — в Dev-C++ сгенерированный ассемблерный код записывается в файл с расширением .exe. Поэтому нужно его просто переименовать в .txt и открыть в блокноте. Также, в папке MinGW32\bin находится компилятор, который можно запустить из командной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое — добавить в опции компиляции (Compiler options -> Add the following commands when calling the compiler) опцию `-save-temps`. Тогда ассемблерный код будет в файлах с расширением .s. Другой вариант — использовать опцию `-Wa,-adhln=test.s` — тогда ассемблерный код будет в файле test.s.